# Two different ways to approach storing multiple pieces of data in a database. Which should I choose?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store product images.
Each product will have more than one image

**Approach 1:**

```
table products 
table productImages
```

with contents:

```
productId productPhoto
1     -    28374628
1     -    12731283
2     -    23498723
3     -    23849723
```

**Approach 2:**

table products
in it, there is a table productPhotos 
and in it there is one long string that contains all the product images ids, separated by a comma. if I want to add one more image, I have to concatenate it.

I have been debating this with some friends and opinions are devided.

I consider the first approach much better because it is more object-oriented and I think normalisation is at a better level this way.

Opponents of my approach say that it will not perform as well as the string/separators approach when there is more activity in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Go with Approach 1. You can easily join tables with that design and don't have to break your head on seperating the content in that column or search for a specific id in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Chose approach one. It's normalised, will enable you to work with your data in a standard, understandable way.

It will also be easier to extend it (what if you need to add more columns?)

It will be much easier and quicker to add and remove additional photos as well as query them. Database systems are designed to work with normalised data and are efficient at this - you don't need to try to improve it.